# Python Issues Creating a Definition to merge two datasets - using a string to reference and vars()

Tags: python

I am trying to merge two datasets and can get the two datasets merged with no issue outside of a definition:

```
year = 2014
a = "text_"+str(year)
b = vars()[a]
full = datamerge(year).set_index('FileName').join(b.set_index('FileName'))
```

This creates the merged dataframe I want. However when I use a definition:

```
def datawithname(year):
    a = "text_"+str(year)
    b = vars()[a]
    full = datamerge(year).set_index('FileName').join(b.set_index('FileName'))
    return(full)

datawithname(2014)
```

It gives me a KeyError: 'text_2014'

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-e168f3386261> in <module>
----> 1 datawithname(2014)

<ipython-input-204-0c844027fc3e> in datawithname(year)
      2 def datawithname(year):
      3     a = "text_"+str(year)
----> 4     b = vars()[a]
      5     full = datamerge(year).set_index('FileName').join(b.set_index('FileName'))
      6     return(full)

KeyError: 'text_2014'
```

Comment: b = vars()['a']

Answer (score 0):

Since `'a'` gets evaluated inside the brackets, 
calling `vars()[a]` is the same as calling `vars()['text_2014']`.
 `vars()` returns a dictionary with the variable names as key, *not* the variable values as keys.

You need to change:

```
b = vars()[a]
```

to:

```
b = vars()['a']
```

Comment: I just tried that and it gives an attributerror that string has no attribute set_index. The solution doesn't make sense since the first snippet of code works. Please clarify if you meant something else.

Comment: @TopcueLee That came from a different part of your code. Apparently, `datamerge(year)` returns a string, and so, you cannot do `datamerge(year).set_index`

Comment: The code was run within the same framework. datamerge(year) returns a dataframe. text_2014 is a dataframe. The initial snippet of code works as intended. When I try to build a definition, the code does not work. All input variables for both the def and the stand alone code are the same.